# Unix solution to logging with rotation and cleanups

Tags: ubuntu, bash, unix, logging

Given we have various types of applications running in a unix system via tmux. Those applications can be java, node, go or anything that outputs to stdout...

Is there a good solution for unix systems (specifically i care for ubuntu 18.04) which would allow me to log all the stdout/stderr output into log files (just like java log4j), rollover daily, and delete logs older than N days...

I'm looking for unix solution since it is not maintainable to force those application to do logging properly on their own... their technological availability is different and there are number of libraries in node that log to stdout already.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have never done this but it seems possible with `tmux pipe-pane` (via `tmux set-hook` maybe) + `logrotate`.

Comment: newsyslog might also be an option.

Comment: I rarely see problems with syslogd/newsyslog working together for logging and rotating. The product I work on still uses that at the enterprise level managing logging from dozens of services under extremely heavy load and we usually only see problems from syslogd missing messages rather than from newsyslog rolling logs.